# PUT or PATCH `_method` param not working or not being respected in rails-api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

### TLDR:

*Using `rails --api`, expected rails to route as `PUT` method from `POST and params[:_method]='put'`, but is routing as `POST`*

### Given:

- **rails 4.2.8**
- **rails-api 0.4.1**

Consider the following:

**config/routes.rb:**

```
resources :sessions, do
  put 'authenticate', on: :collection
end
```

**some client HTML file:**

```
<form action='http://localhost:3000/sessions/authenticate' method='post'>
  <input type='hidden' name='_method' value='put'>
  ...
</form>
```

...upon form submit:

**`rails server` output:**

```
Started POST "/sessions/authenticate" for ::1 at 2018-03-07 11:20:21 +0000
No route matches [POST] "/sessions/authenticate" excluded from capture: DSN not set

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/sessions/authenticate"):
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  ...
```

Inspecting Chrome -> Developer Tools -> Network tab -> [REQUEST], the payload is correct as shown below:

> **General**
>   Request URL:http://localhost:3000/sessions/authenticate
>   ...
>
> **FormData**
>   _method:put
>   ...

### Troubleshooting

- I tried copying the exact code in a new rails project, but this time not using the `--api` mode, and the request worked: that it recognised the `_method='PUT'` and route as a `PUT` properly. So, I have a feeling that this just got to do with some differences between normal rails and the api mode. Unfortunately, after several searches I couldn't find any solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what gem/package/... do you use to query your endpoints ?

Comment: @Ben I just updated my question to include `rails-api 0.4.1`. But if you were talking about the form that "posts" itself, I'm not using anything, it's just a simple `.html` file.

Comment: ok i see; obviously the answer worked out; was asking because I tend to query rails endpoints with axios or related tools; they work like a charm by simply specifying a PUT or PATCH method

Comment: @Ben ohh i see like `postman`? Yes specifying `PUT` as the HTTP method worked in Postman, but specifying `POST` and `_method='put'` didn't work on Postman. But thank you for your help!!! :)

Comment: yep for sure sergio is providing an accurate solution; rails_api needed here (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Handling of `_method` hidden fields is done by a piece of rack middleware.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-middleware

> **Rack::MethodOverride** allows the method to be overridden if `params[:_method]` is set. This is the middleware which supports the PATCH, PUT, and DELETE HTTP method types.

I'm guessing you don't have that in api mode. Add it and the request should be routed correctly.

#### Bonus track

I didn't know this myself (or forgot a long time ago). Here's how I found out.

1. Go to https://github.com/rails/rails and try to search that repo for `:_method` (as this is likely how rails would address the field). After two minutes realize that github doesn't search the exact term.
2. Clone rails repo locally (5 mins)
3. Grep the local codebase (0.5 seconds)

   ```
   sergio@soviet-russia ‹ master › : ~/projects/github/rails
   [0] % ag ":_method"
   guides/source/rails_on_rack.md
   238:* Allows the method to be overridden if `params[:_method]` is set. This is the middleware which supports the PUT and DELETE HTTP method types.

   guides/source/configuring.md
   235:* `Rack::MethodOverride` allows the method to be overridden if `params[:_method]` is set. This is the middleware which supports the PATCH, PUT, and DELETE HTTP method types.
   ```

Total time taken: ~7 minutes. Rails itself actually didn't contain actual relevant code, but it had the docs. I got lucky. :)

Comment: That did the trick!!!! Been stuck on this for 2 hours now! Thanks!!! :)

Comment: Ahh thanks for the detailed troubleshooting steps!! I'll start doing like this now too! :D

Comment: Thank you, thank you, and thank you again. Got my engine to run inside a rails API and was hitting this issue. Added `config.middleware.use(Rack::MethodOverride)` to my `engine.rb` and forms submit with patch.